# What could be the problem, if I use fwrite(3) instead of write(2), in the socket program?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, system-calls

I want know that what the problem could be in case that I use fwrite(3) instead of write(2). It is socket programs.

I am expecting the flush problems.

Is there any other problem?

I am considering the following cost.

1. The cost of mode switching between user mode and kernel mode (Context Switching, etc.) is quite expensive.
2. The system call has the switching cost problem between user mode and kernel mode.
3. I want to avoid performance degradation by reducing system calls as much as possible.
4. And, I want to maintain the real-time performance of the socket program.

Comment: Why do you want to use `fwrite` instead? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: How is flushing a problem? I mean, other than needing to do it when all current data is `fwrite`'d.

Comment: In man write(2), there is a bug for the thread I/O operation on Linux before version 3.14. Because fwrite(3) is thread safe, I think that the fwrite has an advantage on linux before 3.14. Yes, it is very ambiguous reason.

Comment: @hyde Yes, you are right. I just assume a situation where they need to communicate with each other in real time. In this case, the delay due to the flush is also not allowed.

Comment: That bug you mention, will your code ever run on such old systems as from before Linux 3.14? Also the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html#BUGS) says it's about file positioning, which doesn't seem relevant for sockets. Also note that `fwrite` will use `write`, there's really no way around it on a Linux (or other POSIX) system.

Comment: @Some programmer dude
 ah.. you are right. This was not my initial intention. I was mistaken. I added my first intention to the post by ps. Thank you.

Comment: `fwrite` + flush shouldn't introduce any extra delay. If anything, it may reduce the delay, by indirectly enabling better network packet splits.

Comment: @hyde Are you saying that it can be recommended to use fwrite rather than write? Then, in this case, it can be seen that it is better to use the c library than the system call.

Comment: @3088K If the FILE* buffering mechanism fits your need, and otherwise you'd write your own buffering, then it's worth a consideration.

Comment: fwrite() uses an internal buffering mechanism to buffer data, and write() to actually pass it forwards.  With sockets, you'll get better defined behaviour with [send() or sendto() or sendmsg()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html), or if you can send many packets in a single call, then [sendmmsg()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmmsg.2.html).  Note: [send*() do not do short writes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html), whereas [write() can](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) on sockets.